# How to Replace primary key in an INSERT Where the value exist?

Tags: mysql, sql

I create a new db (usuarios) and i want to insert old values into a new table but my SQL backup also saved the auto_increment value and it is the primary key so when i import the file an error message show and it is due to the primary key value is already used in the new table, for instance:

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios` VALUES
(5, 'USERBETA', 'USERINFO')
```

It says that the primary key 5 is duplicated. How can I fix this to ignore the old auto_increment value and use the a new one instead?

Comment: You can specify the columns to insert.  `INSERT INTO usuarios (col2, col3) VALUES ('USERBETA', 'USERINFO')`

Comment: Do you have to use the key provided if it doesn't exist in the table? Otherwise just use `(null, 'USERBETA', 'USERINFO')` in your `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** This query will change your existing data to use much larger ID numbers, at which point you could then import the old data. There should be no ambiguity as long as you move existing table data IDs to a large enough number, and then import the old data.

```
UPDATE usuarios SET id = (id+10000)
```

*(10000 is arbitrary, it should be some number larger than the largest existing ID in old data)*

Then re-set your ID number at 1:

```
ALTER TABLE `usuarios` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Then import your data.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you don't have relational tables (nothing depending on the fixed ID's already set in table `usuarios`) then you can just import without the `id` column. But, if you need to keep those old `id` already assigned, you could turn off auto_increment before import and then re-enable once you've inserted everything.

Presuming `id` is the column of your id:

Remove any existing (old) data:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE usuarios
```

Remove the auto_increment

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios CHANGE `id` INT(11) NOT NULL
```

Import your data like you have been.

Then, re-add the auto_increment:

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios MODIFY `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `usuarios` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1234;
```

Comment: Auto-increment isn't the problem. The problem is that he's already inserted data into the new table, and those IDs conflict with the IDs of the data he's trying to merge into it. Truncating the table will lose all that data.

Comment: I see. If that's the case, couldn't he migrate the existing data into higher ID #s? `UPDATE usuarios SET id = (id+10000)` (or some number larger than the largest existing ID in old data) and then import?

Comment: That's what he's asking how to do!

Comment: my exported file has those old id values, i want to ignore them when i am inserting them in the new table

Comment: Why go with higher id values.. you could reach a clash. What's wrong with negative numbers?

Comment: thanks to all guys, i did as @SetSailMedia say, updating the id before export. i just calculate how to put it as the next value in my new table